# Average Distance Between Two Nodes In An Unweighted Tree

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory, trees, random-graphs

Given a **random** unweighted tree with $n$ vertices, what would be an average minimal distance between two of its vertices?

To put it in a more formal way, let's denote the set of all trees with $n$ vertices as $T_n$ and minimal distance between nodes $i$ and $j$ in a tree $t$ as $d_t(i, j)$, then what would be the value of:

$$\frac{1}{n^n} \cdot \sum_{t\in T_n} \left(\sum_{i,j \in [0; n-1]} d_t(i,j)\right)$$

Comment: To clarify the formula: there're $n^{n-2}$ trees with $n$ vertices, and there're $n^2$ possible $i, j$ combinations, bringing the total to $n^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the count of $n^{n-2}$, I take it you’re talking about labelled trees.

It doesn’t matter which pair of vertices we consider, so let’s consider the two with highest indices, $n$ and $n-1$, and let’s see what happens in the construction of the tree’s [Prüfer sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) if these two vertices are at a distance $d$ from each other. We remove all leaves until we’re left with just these two vertices and the ones between them. From then on, none of the indices in the Prüfer sequence is $n$ or $n-1$, and all the remaining indices are different. Conversely, if at some point all remaining indices are different and none are $n$ or $n-1$, then all the vertices with those indices must be between $n$ and $n-1$. Thus, the average distance is

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[d]
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n-2}n\cdot\frac{n-3}n\cdots\frac{n-2-(k-1)}n\cdot\frac{k+2}n\cdot(k+1)
\\
&=&
(n-2)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^{-(k+1)}(k+2)(k+1)}{(n-2-k)!}
\\
&=&
(n-2)!\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^{-(n-1-j)}(n-j)(n-1-j)}{j!}
\\
&=&
\frac{(n-2)!}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^j(n-j)(n-1-j)}{j!}
\\
&=&
\frac{(n-2)!}{n^{n-2}}\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^j}{j!}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(n-2)!}{n^k(n-2-k)!}
\\
&=&
1+\frac{n-2}n+\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n^2}+\cdots
\\
&\approx&
1+\exp\left(-\frac2n\right)+\exp\left(-\frac2n-\frac3n\right)+\cdots
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\exp\left(-\frac{k^2+3k}{2n}\right)
\\
&\approx&
\int_{-\frac12}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{k^2+3k}{2n}\right)\mathrm dk
\\
&\approx&
\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}2}-1\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Here’s a table up to $n=6$:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
\mathsf E[d]&1&\frac43&\frac{13}8&\frac{236}{125}&\frac{115}{54}
\end{array}

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20of%20%7B%7B%28n%2F%28n-1%29%29%20*%20%28%28e%2Fn%29%5En%20Gamma%28n%2B1%2Cn%29-2%29%2Csqrt%28pi%20*%20n%20%2F%202%29%20-%201%7D%7D%20for%20n%3D0..100)’s a plot that compares the exact values up to $n=100$ with the asymptotic result. There error is of order $n^{-\frac12}$.

Comment: (+1) One way to skip to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(n-2)!}{n^k(n-2-k)!}$ is that $\frac{(n-2)!}{n^k(n-2-k)!}$ is the probability that the last $k$ digits of the Prüfer code are distinct from each other and $\{n-1,n\}$. By the argument at the beginning, this is the probability $\Pr[d(n-1,n) \ge k+1]$. The sum $\sum_{k\ge 0} \Pr[d(n-1,n) \ge k+1]$ is equal to $\mathbb E[d(n-1,n)]$: a standard trick for expected values.